# How to save settings in texstudio?

Tags: texstudio, editors

I've changed some shortcuts in texstudio and saved them. I am not an expert of programming but I can see some relevant text regarding the saved shortcuts in `texstudio.ini` file as follows:

```
keysetting\1\id=main/latex/environment/center~0
keysetting\1\key=Ctrl+Shift+C
keysetting\2\id=main/latex/environment/flushleft~0
keysetting\2\key=Ctrl+Shift+L
keysetting\3\id=main/latex/environment/flushright~0
keysetting\3\key=Ctrl+Shift+R
keysetting\4\id=main/latex/listenvironment/itemize~0
keysetting\4\key=Ctrl+Shift+I
keysetting\5\id=main/latex/listenvironment/enumerate~0
keysetting\5\key=Ctrl+Shift+E
keysetting\6\id=main/latex/listenvironment/item~0
keysetting\6\key=Ctrl+I
```

These are some of the pairs of key combinations and the actions set by me. I followed very simple steps.

1. I changed the shortcuts from `Options` > `Configure TeXstudio` > `Shortcuts`.
2. They appeared to me on the `Current Shortcuts` tab of the page.
3. I saved the changes by `Options` > `Save Current Settings`.

And the changes were saved. Now when I'm trying to save some more shortcuts with the same process, it is not working. When a particular session is expired, all the changes are lost.

Three questions -

- What is wrong with it?
- Can somebody explain how to write a desired
  shortcut in this language?
- Can we change the shortcuts in the
  `Default Shortcuts` tab?

PS - I want to edit the shortcuts in the `Sectioning` and the `Tabular Environment` tabs.

Comment: have you tried loading your custom settings?

Comment: You mean to say load profile?

Comment: yes, exactly what I meant.

Comment: Yes. I've tried. Still it doesn't work.